# Flask-SQLAlchemy: CircularDependencyError where same row in many-to-one relationship can be in one-to-many relationship with same table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, relationship, flask-sqlalchemy, circular-dependency

I'm using Flask-SQLAlchemy 2.1 with SQLAlchemy 1.0.13, and I have two tables, `Address` and `Customer` that have multiple relationships to each other, as follows:

```
class Address(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ...  # Other rows including first_name, last_name, etc.
    customer_id = db.Column(
        db.Integer,
        db.ForeignKey('customers.id')
    )
    customer = db.relationship(
        'Customer',
        foreign_keys=customer_id,
        back_populates='addresses'
    )

class Customer(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    billing_address_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('addresses.id'))
    billing_address = db.relationship(
        'Address',
        foreign_keys=billing_address_id
    )
    shipping_address_id = db.Column(
        db.Integer,
        db.ForeignKey('addresses.id')
    )
    shipping_address = db.relationship(
        'Address',
        foreign_keys=shipping_address_id
    )
    addresses = db.relationship(
        'Address',
        foreign_keys='Address.customer_id',
        back_populates='customer'
    )
```

There are also two event listeners that automatically add any set `billing_address` or `shipping_address` to `addresses` for `Customer` instances:

```
@event.listens_for(Customer.billing_address, 'set')
def add_billing_address_event(target, value, oldvalue, initiator):
    """If a billing address is added to a `Customer`, add it to addresses."""
    if value is not None and value not in target.addresses:
        target.addresses.append(value)


@event.listens_for(Customer.shipping_address, 'set')
def add_shipping_address_event(target, value, oldvalue, initiator):
    """If a shipping address is added to `Customer`, add to addresses."""
    if value is not None and value not in target.addresses:
        target.addresses.append(value)
```

Attempting to set `Customer.billing_address` and `Customer.shipping_address` results in a `CircularDependencyError` as I would expect:

```
> c = Customer()
> c.billing_address = Address(first_name='Bill')
> c.shipping_address = Address(first_name='Ship')
> db.session.add(c)
> db.session.flush()

CircularDependencyError: Circular dependency detected. (ProcessState(ManyToOneDP(Customer.shipping_address), <Customer at 0x7f53aa5c9fd0>, delete=False), ProcessState(ManyToOneDP(Address.customer), <Address at 0x7f53aa4e4128>, delete=False), ProcessState(ManyToOneDP(Address.customer), <Address at 0x7f53aa4e4080>, delete=False), SaveUpdateState(<Customer at 0x7f53aa5c9fd0>), ProcessState(ManyToOneDP(Customer.billing_address), <Customer at 0x7f53aa5c9fd0>, delete=False), ProcessState(OneToManyDP(Customer.addresses), <Customer at 0x7f53aa5c9fd0>, delete=False), SaveUpdateState(<Address at 0x7f53aa4e4080>), SaveUpdateState(<Address at 0x7f53aa4e4128>))
```

If I comment out the event listeners, this does not cause the `CircularDependencyError`, which is also what I would expect, as `Customer.address` is not being accessed. This is not a solution, however, as the circular dependency results from having the same `Address` instance exist in `billing_address` or `shipping_address` and `addresses`, and I would like to allow `addresses` to include current billing and shipping addresses.

According to the [relevant SQLAlchemy docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationship_persistence.html#rows-that-point-to-themselves-mutually-dependent-rows) this should be fixable by adding `post_update=True` argument to one side of the relationship, and giving its foreign key a name:

```
class Address(db.Model):
    ...
    customer_id = db.Column(
        db.Integer,
        db.ForeignKey('customers.id', name='fk_customer_id')
    )
    customer = db.relationship(
        'Customer',
        foreign_keys=customer_id,
        back_populates='addresses',
        post_update=True
    )
```

This still raises a `CircularDependencyError`, however:

```
CircularDependencyError: Circular dependency detected. (ProcessState(OneToManyDP(Customer.addresses), <Customer at 0x7f620af3ff60>, delete=False), SaveUpdateState(<Address at 0x7f620ae5a080>), SaveUpdateState(<Address at 0x7f620ae5a128>), ProcessState(ManyToOneDP(Customer.billing_address), <Customer at 0x7f620af3ff60>, delete=False), SaveUpdateState(<Customer at 0x7f620af3ff60>), ProcessState(ManyToOneDP(Customer.shipping_address), <Customer at 0x7f620af3ff60>, delete=False))
```

I've also tried passing `use_alter=True` to the `customer_id` foreign key as mentioned in some related StackOverflow posts:

```
customer_id = db.Column(
    db.Integer,
    db.ForeignKey('customers.id', name='fk_customer_id', use_alter=True)
)
```

The `CircularDependencyError` still happens. I have found a solution that seems to work, which I will post below, but I am not confident it is the correct solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `post_update=True` on both sides of the relationship appears to solve the problem:

```
class Address(db.Model):
    ...
    customer_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('customers.id'))
    customer = db.relationship(
        'Customer',
        foreign_keys=customer_id,
        back_populates='addresses',
        post_update=True
    )

class Customer(db.Model):
    ...
    addresses = db.relationship(
        'Address',
        foreign_keys='Address.customer_id',
        back_populates='customer',
        post_update=True
    )
```

Now when adding a `billing_address` and/or a `shipping_address`, it is automatically added to `addresses` without issue. Adding a new `billing_address` or `shipping_address` behaves as I expect it to as well, leaving the old address in `addresses` as well as adding the new one.

I am not completely confident in this answer, however, as the SQLAlchemy documentation explicitly mentions that `post_update=True` should be set for one side of the relationship, not both, so I am wondering if my solution will lead to unexpected behavior.

**Edit - Here's the proper solution:**

For some reason, setting `post_update=True` on `addresses` without also setting it on `customer` (or vice versa) wasn't working, but setting it on `billing_address` and `shipping_address` as suggested by @univerio. Thanks!

```
class Customer(db.Model):
...
    billing_address = db.relationship(
        'Address',
        foreign_keys=billing_address_id,
        post_update=True
    )
    shipping_address = db.relationship(
        'Address',
        foreign_keys=shipping_address_id,
        post_update=True
    )
```

Comment: "The flag should be placed on just one of the relationships", this refers to setting `post_update=True` on either the `addresses` relationship, or, both the `shipping_address` and `billing_address` relationships, not the two sides of the same `addresses`/`customer` relationship.